# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Run attribute's code without reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've defined the following attribute:

```
class MyAttribute: RouteAttribute, IActionModelConvention, IActionHttpMethodProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<string> HttpMethods { get; }

    public MyAttribute(string template) : base(UpdateTemplate(template))
    {
        HttpMethods = new[] { HttpMethod.Post.Method };
    }

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        Foo();
    }
}
```

The idea is to run `Foo()` without the need to use reflection and manually look for methods with the provided attribute.

Now, MVC will run `Apply(action)` only after the web application got its first request. I'm looking for a solution which will cause a method to run inside the attribute context without the need to find it by reflection and run a `Foo()`.

`Foo()` does not have to be necessarily inside the attribute.

---

Any solution that allows me to have the instance of the attribute and on the startup of my application will be greeted.

---

Edit: For clarification, what I am trying to achieve is to use MVC's internal mechanism that searches for classes which implement certain interfaces and runs a certain function they implement. For an example here I used `IActionModelConvention` to run `Foo()` when using said mechanism. The problem here is that Foo() will run only after the routing mechanism is fired which only happens after a request was sent to the application. I'm looking for something to run my code as the application starts and to have my attribute's instance so I can pass `Foo(this.someAttributeField)` to it

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for. I think this question is suffering from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sounds like you are having a design issue here. Not sure what exactly you want to do in there, but you can run this wtihin startup, because during application startup (`ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods) there **is no request** Requests are initialized form outside by the user calling your web application via browser or any other means

Comment: And on a side note, Attributes are like Java annotations. They are just metadata, they never get invoked automatically unless some other code finds them (via reflection) and invokes it. I suggest you go 3 steps back and describe what you want to achieve, since whatever you try to accomplish it seems pretty wrong

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to use MVC's internal mechanism that searches for classes which implement certain interfaces and runs a certain function they implement. For an example here I used `IActionModelConvention` to run `Foo()` when using said mechanism. The problem here is that `Foo()` will run only after the routing mechanism is fired which only happens after a request was sent to the application. I'm looking for something to run my code as the application starts **and** to have my attribute's instance so I can pass `Foo(this.someAttributeField)` to it